# SmartGWT alternatives

Tags: java, gwt, wicket, smartgwt

I have been using SmartGWT but have run into trouble mixing SmartGWT with other frameworks such as Wicket. Infact it has been a bit of a disaster and I regret going with it in the first place.

I do not want this question to turn into any type of flame war, so therefore would just like people to list alternatives and their experience with those alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The post above is actually mine, not too sure what happened but I can give you extra resources if you want to take a look at my recommendation. Below are numerous getting started resources that I found very useful.

- [Tutorial](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Getting_Started/Tutorial)
- [Quick Start](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Installation_Guide/Quick_Start)
- [ZK Essentials](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Essentials) (Recommend to read)
- [Documentation Index](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Documentation)

I would also state that I integrated it with many frameworks and it worked flawlessly.

I did also like working with ICEfaces if you do like the JSF approach, however, that can get rather complex! Personally I prefer ZK's approach, each to their own.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

My company ran a "bake off" between numerous solutions including, the eventual winner ZK, SmartGWT, Wicket and ICEfaces. During this time we also reported some problems when integrating SmartGWT with other frameworks and javascript libraries. This caused us some problems and was one of the reasons why we dropped it.

I would highly recommend you take a look at [ZK](http://www.zkoss.org) as we found it to be excellent for the development and deployment of enterpize applications.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I have used [GXT](http://www.extjs.com/products/gxt/) and I have done some simple integrations with wicket components with it.

Perhaps you can describe the kinds of troubles you are having with the wicket integration, that would help suggest a new library for you to use